# Integers that are a sum of two $k$th powers in $n$ different ways

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Do there exist infinitely many $k$ such that for all $n$ we can find a sequence $x_i$ of distinct natural numbers

such that $x_1^k+x_2^k=x_3^k+x_4^k=\cdots=x_{2n-1}^k+x_{2n}^k$ ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an open problem. Little is known for $k>3$.

In particular, nobody knows if there is a solution of $$x_1^4 + x_2^4 = x_3^4 + x_4^4 = x_5^4 + x_6^4,$$ or $$x_1^5 + x_2^5 = x_3^5 + x_4^5.$$

For details, see Richard K. Guy, *[Unsolved Problems in Number Theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=1AP2CEGxTkgC)*, section D, in the vicinity of pages 211–216. Guy gives an extensive bibliography, and cites Hardy and Wright for the claim that there are numbers that can be expressed as a sum of two cubes in arbitrarily many ways, although examples with $n=3$ and $n=4$ were not found until 1957 and 1991, respectively.

The MathWorld pages on [diophantine equations in 4th powers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation4thPowers.html) and [diophantine equations in 5th powers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation5thPowers.html) contain a lot of interesting information about these and similar equations.

[Jean-Charles Meyrignac's web site](http://euler.free.fr/) includes an enormous table giving, for each $m$ and $k$, the smallest $n$ for which a solution to $$\sum_1^m x_i^k = \sum_1^n y_i^k\tag{$\bullet$}$$ is known. You want $m=n=2$, but for $k>3$ and $m=2$ the best known $n$ in the table is always greater than 2, and increases rapidly with $k$. The site has extensive information about  equation $\bullet$.